# Have problem sending confirmation email to user, after they complete filling out a form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

After a user completes a form, they click the "Submit" button. After that, the user will get an conformation email. In the form, we ask the user to enter their e-mail address, and based on that information, that's how I want to send the confirmation email to the user.

Right now, I am hard coding the e-mail address to myself. But I am wondering is there a way to send the user the conformation email based of the value they enter in the user email address input field?

This how I have it set it up:

```
// hard code my e-mail address for now.
<input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="leamblahblah@gmail.com">

<fieldset>
<div class="myform">
            <label for="user_emailaddress">Enter email address <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input required name="user_emailaddress," type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="youremail@example.com">
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input required name="user_emailaddress," type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="youremail@example.com">

you have a mistake in the name of that field *,*

<input required name="user_emailaddress" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="youremail@example.com">
```

Comment: My question was, how do I send email the user based of their email address value that they typed in the input field for email address?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have an email dispatch function, you can get the value of an input field from javascript.

```
document.querySelector('input[type=email]').value
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ini_set("SMTP", "aspmx.l.google.com");
ini_set("sendmail_from", "YOURMAIL@gmail.com");

$message = "The mail message was sent with the following mail setting:\r\nSMTP = aspmx.l.google.com\r\nsmtp_port = 25\r\nsendmail_from = YourMail@address.com";

$headers = "From: YOURMAIL@gmail.com";

mail("Sending@provider.com", "Testing", $message, $headers);
echo "Check your email now....&lt;BR/>";
```

Comment: This is nowhere related to the question. This is a server-side function that you have given here